# Amazon ami cronjob not accessing Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, cron

I am running this script as ec2-user on amazon ami.

```
include '../cms_config.php';
$tracking_query="select *from cruise_track";
$tracking_result=mysql_query($tracking_query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($tracking_result);
if($tracking_result){$message='success';}
else{$message='fail';}
mail('diversifiers@gmail.com', 'Cronjob email', 'Count:'.$count, $headers);
```

I have this code in a file test.php. When I run this code as a cronjob, script fails to connect with database. However when i run same file through browser it works fine.

Can you please let me know what is the problem and how i can fix this?

Comment: There's no code here that tries to connect to the database.

Comment: so output useful error messages: `$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());` `$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`, etc... don't output "fail" - fixed/unchanging error messages are essentially useless.

Comment: I have included connection at top of this code. This code works fine when i run through browser. But does not work when i set same file as a crontab.

Comment: I just used these error messages here to post question. Real messages are different. Problem is that running same file as cronjob does not access mysql.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Try first cd to your php script dir, e.g. not

```
1 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

but

```
1 0 * * * cd /path/to/your; /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: To run cronjob i used `1 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php` cronjob was working. I was using relative path to include database connection string. I made db connection in same file and it started working. We should use absolute paths within script for cronjob like `/path/to/your/includes.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i figured out the issue. I was using relative path to include my database connection string `include '../cms_config'`. Relative paths does not work when we run script as a cronjob. I made connection to database in same file and fixed my issue. Here is working code.

```
$hostname_connect= "localhost";
$database_connect= "mydb";
$username_connect= "username";
$password_connect= "password";

$connection_string= mysql_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
$dbSelect = mysql_select_db($database_connect) or die (mysql_error());

$tracking_query="select *from `tracks`";
$tracking_result=mysql_query($tracking_query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($tracking_result);
if($tracking_result){$message='success';}
else{$message='fail';}
mail('diversifiers@gmail.com', 'Cronjob email', 'Total Results:'.$count, $headers);
```

So user absolute paths within your cronjob code when including other files and folders.

Comment: bad idea: 1) it is unusable for large projects, you cannot put all in single file 2) absolute paths in code is evil, it makes your code non-movable. This is why I suggested `cd` to the proper dir first.